# How can you interface a JavaFX application running on iOS or Android to native libraries?

Tags: java, android, ios, scala

[Oracle has just announced that they will be open sourcing their iOS and Android implementations of JavaFX](http://fxexperience.com/2013/02/february-open-source-update/). While we wait for the goods to arrive: how would you approach native things, like push notifications, etc? JNI, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RoboVM](http://www.robovm.org) provides a native bridge.